# Why don't browsers download scripts asynchronously by default?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, browser

Browsers evolved so much across time, yet script downloading is still done synchronously (unless explicitly tell otherwise).

I've always wondered why is this functionality not enabled by default?

We have an `async` HTML5 attribute to download it asynchronously, but as asynchronous programming grows bigger and bigger I think that it should really be a `sync` attribute, with asynchronous behaviour by default if not specified.

For instance, consider the following:

```
<script src="src/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="src/angular.js"></script>
<script src="src/index.js"></script>
```

The three of these scripts can be downloaded asynchronously, and *loaded synchronously*.
The browser needs to load them at the same order they were declared, but this shouldn't be relevant when downloading.

Is there any technical reason this hasn't been implemented?

Comment: Newer browsers *do* download scripts in parallel, and then execute them in series - not that there aren't still quirks where sometimes they're downloaded sequentially. (But obviously they do have to be *executed* one after the other.)

Comment: `as asynchronous programming grows bigger and bigger` - well, that's an odd statement. It has no relevance to how scripts are loaded, really - besides, the async attribute has no effect on how scripts are loaded, it `indicates that the browser should, if possible, execute the script asynchronously`

Comment: Did you miss the after almost 20 years version update of HTTP: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2#Goals